# Pre generated views using entity framework power tool are not working

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-power-tools

I am using entity framework with DB first approach. I have migrated from EF5 to EF6 successfully. In EF5, I was using pre generated views to improve startup performance. In EF6, it is not working. I have generated views using power tool. Power tool generated it successfully and I can build the application without any error.

But When I run it, getting following error:

```
The current model no longer matches the model used to pre-generate the mapping views, as indicated by the ViewsForBaseEntitySetsfc4437b421d2fd7f4d645bf31e3cb5b1b8374d9c77a07ef5f36c1cac0bfea31a.MappingHashValue property. 
Pre-generated mapping views must be either regenerated using the current model or removed if mapping views generated at runtime should be used instead
```

I am not able to understand why there is difference between the hash value generated via power tool and generated by EF at run time. There is no change in the edmx file.

There are more than 290 entities in edmx.

Version of entity framework in 6.1.3.
 
Power tool is VSPowerTools-Beta4.
 
I am using visual studio 2013.
Code generation startegy of edmx is 'Legacy ObjectContext'.

Comment: Maybe if you turn off DB Initializer () you able to go around this error. ( ie skip views validation part) http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/turn-off-database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx